# How to show posts ordered by random

Tags: posts, categories

Currently posts in category page arranged by last added, this is the code, please how to make it random

```
if (is_category()) {
        $categories = array(get_query_var('cat'));
        $subcats = get_categories(array('child_of' => get_query_var('cat')));
        if ($subcats) {
            foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
                array_push($categories, $subcat->cat_ID);
            }
        }

        if (of_get_option('show_repins') != 'disable') {            
            $args = array(
                'category__in' => $categories,
                'paged' => $paged
            );
        } else {
            $args = array(
                'category__in' => $categories,
                'paged' => $paged,
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key' => '_Original Post ID',
                        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => '_Original Post ID',
                        'value' => 'deleted'
                    )
                )
            );  
        }
        query_posts($args); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`query_posts()` allows for an argument called `orderby`, there you can provide how you want your posts sorted. So a solution could look like this

```
$args['orderby'] = 'rand';
query_posts($args);
```

For a full list and explanation of the query arguments, check [WordPress Developer Resources on `WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

Comment: is it right?              array(
      'key' => '_Original Post ID',
      'value' => 'deleted'
     )
    )
   ); 
  }
  $args['orderby'] = 'rand';
query_posts($args); 
 }

Comment: @user3415122 Yes sounds right